# Faces are Missing when Import from Blender to Unity

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, import, unity

I am having a very weird issue with Blender. I have created a model of a mansion, with each face on the roof being a flat, solid object. However, when I import the model into Unity, the outer faces of the roof are missing.

I have tried subdividing and triangulating the mesh as other posts have recommended. However, the faces are still not showing in Unity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Outer face shows in blender. Normals included in picture.]
[image: Outer face is missing when imported into Unity]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that the issue was indeed inverted faces. After inverting it in blender the faces rendered correctly.